# Convert Time data type python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to transform a time variable that uses strings and integers in one column into a more friendly format. For example my time variable looks like: 30m 32s

I want a variable in format 30:32
or a variable with number of seconds. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by column? Is your data in a dataframe? Is it a pandas dataframe?

Comment: yes. it is a Data frame

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood the question, but the following will split your string on the space then separate out the individual minutes / seconds.

```
def formatTime(time: str):
     minutes, seconds = time.split(' ') # Split on the space character
     minutes_val = minutes.split('m')[0] # Separate the minutes value
     seconds_val = seconds.split('s')[0] # Separate the seconds value

     return f"{minutes_val}:{seconds_val}" # Return the formatted string
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: as Pranav said in his comment, this won't work for minutes or seconds > 59. So, If you have this limitation, you can use this solution

You can do this using datetime module using the following code

```
from datetime import datetime

time_str = "30m 32s"
time_obj = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%Mm %Ss")
time_in_new_format = time_obj.strftime("%M:%S") # Equals 30:32
```

Now let's explain it line by line.
In the following line, we create a datetime object from the input string and tell the format is `"%Mm %Ss"` as `%M` means minutes and `%S` means seconds.

```
time_obj = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%Mm %Ss")
```

In the following line, we change the datetime object back to a string in the format "%M:%S".

```
time_in_new_format = time_obj.strftime("%M:%S")
```

You can check all formats here https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: This doesn't work for minutes or seconds > 59